# Extracting Full-Average Coefficient from Model Averaged in R

Tags: r, mumin

I am trying to use the full-average coefficient from the model averaged in R.
I am using package (MuMin) at this moment.

However, when I use the argument of:
coef(mAVG_1)
[summary of my model averaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgVG7.png)
It only extract the coefficient of the "conditional average".
Is there any code that can directly extract the coefficient from the full-average model ?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

`?model.avg` says:

> `coef`, `vcov`, `confint` and `coefTable` accept argument `full` that, if set to `TRUE`, the full model-averaged coefficients are returned, rather than subset-averaged ones (when `full = FALSE`, being the default).